# Testing lazily initialized components with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, lazy-loading, react-lazy-load

I am trying to test my lazy initialized component, made with `react-lazy-load-image-component` using JestJS. Below are my tests:

```
const viewModel = new VehicleViewModel(vehicleData, {});

const mockOnClick = jest.fn();

const mockStore = configureStore();

let store: MockStore;

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  store = mockStore(storeInitialState);
});

describe('on component initialization', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SearchResult vehicle={viewModel} onClick={mockOnClick} />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});

describe('when the user clicks on the result', () => {
  it('processes an onClick event', () => {
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SearchResult vehicle={viewModel} onClick={mockOnClick} />
      </Provider>
    );
    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.click(getByTestId('search-result'));
    });
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(mockOnClick).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

The component is coded as:

```
const SearchResult = ({ onClick, vehicle }: SearchResultProps): JSX.Element => {
  const {
    images,
    make,
    model,
    year,
    dealerName,
    city,
    state,
    timeOnMarket,
    mileage,
    price,
  } = vehicle;

  const monthlyPayment = useMonthlyPayment(price);

  return (
    <div className="search-result" data-testid="search-result" onClick={onClick}>
      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
      <div
        className="main-image"
        // replace multiple spaces, if any, with one
        title={`${year || ''} ${make || ''} ${model || ''} image`.replace(/  +/g, ' ')}
      >
        <Carousel images={images} year={year} make={make} model={model} />
        ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

While the `<Carousel />` render is defined as:

```
  return (
    <LazyLoadComponent>
      <div
        className="carousel-container"
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnterEvent}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeaveEvent}
      >
        ...
      </div>
    </LazyLoadComponent>
  );
```

Without lazy loading, my tests work fine.

Wrapper with lazy loading, my tests fail with: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`. The error happens on `const { container } = render(...`.
I tried to mock the scroll effect. Did not work for me, yet.

How do I add jest coverage to components using lazy load inside?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing the below inside the actual code:

```
const TestLasyWrapper = ({ children }: any) => process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' ?
  <LazyLoadComponent>{children}</LazyLoadComponent> : 
    <>{children}</>;
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but your solution doesn't look like a good option. If I'm not wrong, you have written your component to check if the you're using test environment or not. Isn't that bad?

Comment: bad compared to what?

Comment: I meant component code shouldn't contain code for tests right? I guess it's for the same reason we discourage use of data-testid. I'm fairly new to writing unit-tests so I might be wrong

Answer (score -1):

You have to 'wait' for you component to be loaded, mounted and rendered. Are you using [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) with Jest? If so, you can use `waitFor`, which would poll until the item is added to the DOM.

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(screen.findByText('Foo')).toBeInTheDocument());
```

Comment: my render returns `undefined` though. how do i deal with that? the error happens before the expect, right? how would this work?